# What type of DOM Element?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

```
e.g. if i have this:
<div id='mydiv'>whatever</div>
```

then let say in jQuery, how can I find out that the dom element with id "mydiv" is a DIV or is some other element type.

```
e.g. 
$('#mydiv').????  ?
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
var type = $('#mydiv')[0].tagName

alert(type);
//displays "DIV"
```

Comment: Also the MDN docs say xhtml will produce a lowercase string, so perhaps `.toLowerCase()` before checking would standardise it.

Comment: The answer that suggests jQuery's `is()` function will do the necessary standardisation for you, so that is probably the simplest/safest approach.

Answer (score 50):

Try [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is) which tests if anything in the given set matches another selector:

```
if( $('#mydiv').is('div') ){
  // it's a div
}
```

You can also get the tag this way:

```
$('#mydiv').get(0).tagName // yields: 'DIV'
```

Comment: This is much cleaner as `[0].tagName === "DIV"`.

Answer (score 5):

```
alert($('#mydiv')[0].nodeName);
```

Answer (score 4):

The [.prop()](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) function is a nice way of doing this.

```
// Very jQuery
$('#mydiv').prop('tagName');

// Less jQuery
$('#mydiv')[0].tagName;
```

Both give the same result.

And, as Aram Kocharyan commented, you'll probably want to standardise it with `.toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 1):

`$('#mydiv').get(0).nodeType` if you know there's only one element.  The selector object can contain an array of objects.

`.get()` returns the array of DOM objects, the parameter indexes.  `nodeType` is a property exposed by the DOM that tells you what the type of the DOM node is.  Usually as a String in all caps IIRC.

**CORRECTION** `nodeType` gives you an INT corresponding to a nodeType.  `tagName` is what you want.

Comment: +1 - There's also the subscript operator: `$('#mydiv')[0].nodeType` and tagName: `$('#mydiv')[0].tagName`

Answer (score 1):

```
var domElement = $('#mydiv').get(0);
alert(domElement .tagName);
```

may be of use.