# How to find element type in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an array with different elements inside it. Like array contain input elements and select elements. I want to check for particular type. I tried this but it didn't work

```
var mandotaryElementsArray = $('.mandotary');

$.each(mandotaryElementsArray, function(index, element){

    if (element == input) {

        var $inputElement = $(this);
        var test1;

    } else if (element == select) {

        var $selectElement = $(this);
        var test2;

    }

}); //end of .each()
```

Actually i want to check something that is similar to **instance of** in Java. Here i want to check if element is type of **input** then do this, if element is type of **select** then do this, if element is type of **radiobutton** then do this.. How can i make this check here?
Thanks

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114683/how-to-find-out-what-type-of-dom-element-is

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use either the [`.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName) property (which always returns uppercase for HTML):

```
$('.mandotary').each(function(index, element) {
    if (element.tagName == "INPUT") {
        // code here
    } else if (element.tagName == "SELECT") {
        // code here
    }
});
```

Or, you can use jQuery's [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/):

```
$('.mandotary').each(function(index, element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    if ($element.is('input')) {
        // code here
    } else if ($element.is('select')) {
        // code here
    }
});
```

Even better would probably be to let the selector do all the work for you and just select the items you want for a particular operation and operate on the desired selector like this:

```
$('input.mandotary').hide();
$('select.mandotary').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `.is()` to match the tag name:

```
if (element.is('input'))
```

But ideally rework the code and don't check for tag names in your loop.

Comment: Hi, thanks, Actually in my page there are several elements whom i want to check. Like textField, that i want to check for null, select elements that i want to check if a particular value is selected, check box that i want to check, whether tick or not and so on. So what i did i gave them each a class **mandotary** and got then in array. As i did above. Now if in array i have text field that is input element, then i check for null, if it is select then i can check for value and so on. Now can you tell me how can i better do this thing. As you said **ideally rework the code:)** Thanks