# How to get the type of the DOM element to fix the CSS Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Case: $self isn't what I expected and hence I get the `undefined`. 
To rewrite the CSS selector to be able to call data on the right element, I would like to know what element I have, how can I do that? Is it my "ul", "li" or "a".. I know there is a typeof() for Javscript and another for jQuery, but they return "object", "Array" ect.. Not what I need here.

```
$("#ulElementId").on("click", "li a", function (event) {
    var $self = $(this);
    var foo = $self.data("bar"); // undefined
    $self.GetDOMElementType(); // ???
});
```

**Edit:**

```
$("#aId").data("aDataId", "@(Model.aId)");
```

**Solution:**
Make sure to have the developer tool open (F12) first.

```
$("#ulElementId").on("click", "li a", function (event) {
    var $self = $(this);
    debugger;
    var foo = $self.data("bar"); // 2
});
```

Then go to the "Scripts" to see the clicked element. (It's "Object[a #]" in my case) So It's pretty clear now. It was a "a" element. And I can click it and go to it.
Turns out foo wasn't undefined but had the right value.. :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What type of DOM Element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114683/what-type-of-dom-element)

Comment: I want to use jQuery. Can I use tagName ?

Comment: Since you are binding it explicitly to `<a>` tags, whats the need to query it. It will always be `<a>`

Comment: `this` will be `a`...what did you expect? you listen to clicks on an `a` element, what else could `$self` be but `a` ?

Comment: can you post your html-markup too ? would be easer to comprehend the desired behaviour ...

Comment: put in `console.log($self);` and it should appear in your browser's console. Alternatively you could put a watch on self and a breakpoint in the browser's debug tool.

Comment: @gaynorvader what should I look for in the developer tool? I can use that too, it would be nice too so I don't even have to write a test line.

Comment: $gaynorvader your comment is the perfect answer for me. If you make an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in `console.log($self);` and it should appear in your browser's console. Alternatively you could put a watch on `$self` and a breakpoint in the browser's debug tool (F12 menu)